# Classic ASP: Call a VBscript function in form which is returned by a VBScript

Tags: html, forms, asp-classic

I'M a little confused atm. I  am (have to...) working with classic asp to implement an include for a larger website. I have no influence on the coding language so please don't blame for the languae or structure...

So this is my function:

```
function MaintMod2(modcmd)
if CheckUserRights2("M.Write") or CheckUserRights2("M.Read") then

response.write("<div class=""formContainer"">"&_
    "<form action="">"&_
    "<span> CI: <input type=""text"" name=""CI"" value=""byitm6""></span>"&_
    "<span> Start: <input type=""text"" name=""Start"" value=""01.03.2013 - 07:30:17""></span>"&_
    "<span> End: <input type=""text"" name=""End"" value=""15.04.2013 - 11:37:33""></span>"&_
    "<span> Active: <input type=""checkbox"" name=""Active"" value=""Active""></span>"&_
    "<input type=""submit"" class=""button"" id=""formSend"">"&_
    "</form>"&_
"</div>")
end function
```

The main page (which isn't maintained by me) the MaintMod2 function is called to render the new page. So I use "response.write" to generate my HTML.

My Question: How can I call from the form action?

```
<form action="myfunction()">
```

This was my first idea, but it doesn't really work :D

Comment: Preventing missunderdandings: Is 'myfunction()' a clientside or a serverside function. I ask, because VBScript can run on client and serverside.

Comment: Should be server side. Myfunction is supposed to display data using the form parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my eyes, I agree with [call VBScript Sub in a href onclick (classic ASP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123914/call-vbscript-sub-in-a-href-onclick-classic-asp?rq=1) .

The form action starts an action on clientside. If it's possible create a valid link to the page that points to site with this function. Add a parameter to the URL so you can identify the action for invoking your method. On serverside evaluate this parameter and execute your target method (similar to the MVC way).

Comment: Okay, I got my solution:

I use method="post" and action="?Cmd=MaintMod2". Now I can fetch the data with request.form("variable")...

This solutions sucks as hell, but it works :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how your code can work because your example is missing a closing statement of "end if" just before "end function". So the last 2 lines should be...

```
end if
end function
```